# Are archived articles automatically deleted after a period of time?

Tags: knowledge

I thought I had read in the documentation somewhere that archived knowledge articles were automatically deleted after 18 months. However, after trying to relocate this statement in the documentation I cannot find it. Perhaps I misinterpreted something, or am simply wrong.

Can anyone confirm if archived articles are deleted automatically after a specific period of time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After doing a lot more digging I came across the following in the documentation. This suggests that archived articles are not deleted after a specific amount of time, but a specific number of archived versions.

> By default, the system stores up to ten versions of an article, plus
>   any versions that are attached to cases.

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=knowledge_article_versions.htm&type=5